# How to send a List to the other razor page by "HttpContext.Session.Set" in Core 6?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have saved some rows of data in a list named "***viewListNextWeek***". I want to send this list to the next razor page, where I'm redirecting to it by

```
return RedirectToPage("../Food/nextWeekFood");
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55269087/define-and-obtain-a-list-of-asp-net-core-session), I have tried

```
HttpContext.Session.Set<List<reserveInfo>>("List", viewListNextWeek);
```

But I got the error

```
Error   CS0308  The non-generic method 'ISession.Set(string, byte[])' cannot be used with type arguments
```

I also read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0), but I don't understand very well what to do.

Comment: SO you want to set list of value in session?

Comment: You could serlize the object and pass it with TempData when you redirect to another action,the case related :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extension method to save list of data into session. please refer to this simple demo:

```
public static class TestSession
    {
        //set session
        public static void SetObjectsession(this ISession session, string key, object value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }

        //get session
        public static T GetObjectsession<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);
            return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }
    }
```

Then use this method to set and get session:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetObjectsession("A", viewListNextWeek);

HttpContext.Session.GetObjectsession<List<reserveInfo>>("A");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You solved my days problem.